# Reducing data with data stage

Tags: etl, datastage

I've been asked to reduce an existing data model using Data Stage ETL.
It's more of an exercice and a way to get to know this program which I'm very new to.

Of course, the data shall be reduced following some functionnal rules.

Table : MEMBERSHIP (..,A,B,C) # where A,B,C are different attributes (our filters)

Reducing data from ~700k rows to 7k rows or so.

I was thinking about keeping the same percentage as in the data source.
Therefore if we have the 70% of A, 20% of B and 10% of C, we would pretty much have the same percentage on the reduced version.

I'm looking for the best way to do so and the inner tools to use(maybe with the aggregator stage?). 
Is there any way to do some scripting similar to PL with DataStage ? 
I hope I've been clear enough. If you have any advice I'd be very grateful.

Thanks to all of you.

~Whitoo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datastage does not do percentage wise reductions

What you can do is to use a tranformer stage or a filter stage to filter out the data from the source based on certain conditions. But like I said conditions have to be very specific. (for example - select only those records which have A = [somevalue] or A not= [somevalue])

Comment: Hi Ashish and thanks for the reply. I get what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

DataStage PX has the sample stage that allows you to specify what percent of data you want it to sample: http://datastage4you.blogspot.com/2014/01/sample-stage-in-datastage.html.